# Propel: negate multiple conditions

Tags: php, orm, where-clause, propel

I need to negate multiple conditions at once using Propel. E. g. a corresponding sql condition is:

```
WHERE !(something = 'a' and someOtherThing = 'b')
```

I couldn't find a way to solve this using Propel ORM. Is there a way to build this query with the Criteria-API that Propel 1.3 provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the equivalent:
something != 'a' or someOtherThing != 'b'